# Fetching an image from S3 bucket is not working because of CORS

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, axios, cors, fetch-api

The problem is i am getting the cors error (response header does not contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) when i try to fetch using `fetch` API. Here is my cors config in S3 -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The code can be found here - 
https://codepen.io/sourov0805045/pen/OKVBXM?editors=1111

I have checked the response header and saw it does not contain the `Allow-Access-Control-Origin` header.

But this works properly if i add this in a `<img>` tag which is quite puzzling. That time there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response header as well but the image loads properly.

A have tried the same with `axios` with no effect.

Please let me know you suggestion on how can i solve this problem.

Comment: CORS on S3 is broken if you request an object in a same-origin context and then in a cross-origin context, because S3 does not add a `Vary: Origin` response header on non-CORS responses.  I worked through this defect at https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161 which includes references to CloudFront, but S3 is the source of the problem, whether or not CloudFront is used.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot I think my problem is more basic. If you see the codepen, you will see that i am just making a single fetch request, so its not really using the cache. Besides the problem is reproducible in firefox as well.

Comment: Did you already solve this? I am getting the correct response headers now when clicking on the button in your codepen editor:

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 1573767
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 19:41:17 GMT
ETag: "8e26c03714ab4d8e185c29b1c04639f0"
Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Jun 2019 19:18:40 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2: [...]
x-amz-request-id: [...]

Comment: Yeah, it is solved, will update the question later.

Comment: I did create a bucket with your cors config without any issue. Posting how you solved it as an answer can really help future visitors, unless you solved it creating a new bucket.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov Any chance you could provide the update you promised :D?

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov would it be possible to get your explanation on how your solved the issue?

Answer (score 4):

First start off by removing un-necessary variables: use cURL from the command line.

Step 1: Issue the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://example.com" \
      -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
      -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With" \
      -X OPTIONS --verbose \
      'https://twisker-s3-files.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/files/-GxfyX_dZ-6313383.jpg'
```

The response headers you are looking for in the output are:

```
...
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
< Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
...
```

Step 2: Issue the `GET` request:

```
~ $ curl --head 'https://twisker-s3-files.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/files/-GxfyX_dZ-6313383.jpg' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36' -H 'Referer: https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/index.html?editors=1111&key=iFrameKey-a88ea9ee-51a6-0ae2-7350-951a5b1e4e56' -H 'Origin: https://cdpn.io' --compressed
```

Here is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: 9D3J5BnHo7YocXQicso+eQAC/PlyoOMpc5QXd+G77HMtWTOd8kYymcJnQ0T8J7tqXetMZgVO8Rw=
x-amz-request-id: 6CE1579D5B039163
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2019 02:18:41 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Jun 2019 19:18:40 GMT
ETag: "8e26c03714ab4d8e185c29b1c04639f0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1573767
Server: AmazonS3
```

Few things of note:

1. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` exist
2. Their values look to be correct, so CORS should work for you (it did for me on your URL)

https://www.test-cors.org can be used to test CORS requests.  It gives some output on each phase of the request.

Last, browsers are very aggressive on caching the pre-flight OPTIONS request.  So if you are looking at chrome network debug tools, you may not see the pre-flight OPTIONS request.  Sometimes re-starting chrome will clear the OPTIONS cache, sometimes it requires clearing all the browser cache.

This caching can be problematic if you don't have CORS correctly configured server side, and the browser caches the response.  Ex: you don't allow `GET` when you initially configure CORS.  You issue the `OPTIONS` request and the browser caches the response, blocking future `GET` requests.

Comment: thank you for this answer, couldn't figure out why I couldn't load an svg with CORS set to allow all origins in AWS

Answer (score 1):

Since S3 links start with `//` it will use the current protocol to make request. If you have `http://localhost` AWS won't allow you to make request over http, even if the `AllowedOrigins` is `*`.

Prefix URL with `https` in axios url param, and it should work.

Comment: sorry, how do you prefix the URL  with https?

Comment: This is an old answer, but if you want to change protocol you can use  [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way `AllowedOrigins` value configuration is perceived by the S3 internally. Try giving `https://*.yourdomain.com` instead of `https://something.yourdomain.com` in your S3 bucket level CORS Configuration, Here is my sample configuration and it works!

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://*.yourdomain.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow all origins

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        **"AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],**
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
];
```

add this permission in Bucket->permission->Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)
than edit CORS